# how to avoid TO_TENSOR() clips values to 1

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a black and white image that needs to be converted into tensor.
The shape of the image is `(400, 600, 3)`.
Originally, the values of the image have max = 255; for example:

```
org_img[0]
 
# result:
array([[255, 255, 255],
               [255, 255, 255],
               [255, 255, 255],
               ...,
               [255, 255, 255],
               [255, 255, 255],
               [255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

but after i convert into tensor using to_tensor(), it clips my value into 1.

```
torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(org_img[0])
# result:
tensor([[[1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.],
         ...,
         [1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

This makes my image all black, how can i avoid this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are not clipped but instead re-scaled from `uint8` 0..255 to `float32` [0, 1] by `ToTensor`. Library such as `matplotlib` can naturally handle RGB images with single-precision pixel values within [0, 1] after re-scaling.